# Import Large Dataset with Tabs

Tags: r, fread, read.table

When importing a large datset (50GB) there is a significant issue given 'breaks' caused in the data. I have pulled the data into a text editor and can see that the issue is in a certain column where the text overflows over several lines. A brief example for a 8 column data frame is as follows:

```
1001;;x;t;Buy;A great blue car;200;h
1002;;x;t;Buy;A great red car;300;u
1003;;x;t;Buy;A great yellow car;800;u
1004;;x;t;Buy;A great white
car with more text

and more text;200;h
1005;;x;t;Buy;A great yellow car;800;u
```

What I'd like to do is combine the data into an 8 column frame to allow the data to be read into R correctly using fread. The correct solution would look as follows:

```
1001;;x;t;Buy;A great blue car;200;h
1002;;x;t;Buy;A great red car;300;u
1003;;x;t;Buy;A great yellow car;800;u
1004;;x;t;Buy;A great whitecar with more textand more text;200;h
1005;;x;t;Buy;A great yellow car;800;u
```

Comment: It maybe easiest to edit you data before trying to import e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255035/53432

Comment: If you can not edit your data, check the documentation for `fread`. You can use `sep`, `sep2`, `colClasses` and `quote` to get R to read in the columns the way you want (quotes and back/forward slashes can interfere with reading in data). Providing the `nrows` argument will force R to read in data past a few empty rows (happens on occasion).